# doc-view-mode broken after OS X upgrade

Tags: emacs

I recently updated OS X and now my Emacs install cannot open PDFs.  I get the error message

```
No PNG support is available, or some conversion utility for pdf files is missing.
```

when trying to switch to doc-view-mode on a PDF.  This was working before the upgrade but now I can't figure out what's wrong.  I made sure I had xpdf and ghostscript installed through brew.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely, the `$PATH` or `exec-path` have changed during the OSX upgrade.  Personally, I like to use absolute paths for executables -- but you may also adjust either of the aforementioned values.  Here is an example for OSX, Window XP and Windows 7 -- the executable program location will vary depending upon where it was installed:

```lisp
(setq doc-view-ghostscript-program
  (cond
    ((eq system-type 'darwin)
      "/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/bin/gs")
    ((and
        (eq system-type 'windows-nt)
        (equal (w32-version) '(5 1 2600)))
      "c:/Program Files/gs/gs9.14/bin/gswin32c.exe")
    ((and
        (eq system-type 'windows-nt)
        (equal (w32-version) '(6 1 7601)))
      "c:/Program Files/gs/gs9.14/bin/gswin32c.exe")))
```

---

The following command can be used to see the current `$PATH` used by Emacs:

```
M-x eval-expression RET (getenv "PATH") RET
```

Once the location of "gs" has been determined, the original poster can add it to the Emacs `$PATH` if needed -- e.g.,

```
(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/path/to/folder-containing-gs"))
```

---

I'll let another forum participant handle the `exec-path` example, since I don't presently use it -- but here are my notes -- this is untested.

```
(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/path/to/folder-containing-gs")))
```